# How would I make it so that props.match.params.id can be accessed to any of the children Components?

Tags: reactjs, parameters, scope, react-router

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around how to structure a ReactJS application. Here's the relevant information:

**Dev Environment**: npm, webpack

**Dependencies**: React, ReactDOM, React Router, React Router DOM

**Code**: (Cleaned up a bit as to not reveal more sensitive information.)

```
/***********
TABLE OF CONTENTS
01.0.0 - Imports
02.0.0 - Data
03.0.0 - Components
03.1.0 -- Base
03.2.0 -- Location
03.3.0 -- Main
03.3.2 --- Map
04.0.0 - Render
***********/

/* 01.0 Imports */
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';
import {
  HashRouter,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

console.log("Set-up successful");
/* 02.0 Data */
const locationDataArray = {
  locations: [
    {
      "location": "Scenario A",
      "slug": "lipsum",
      "googleUrl": "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Central+Park/@40.7828687,-73.9675438,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c2589a018531e3:0xb9df1f7387a94119!8m2!3d40.7828647!4d-73.9653551",
      "mapUrl": "locations/scenA/main-map.png",
      "areaMaps": [
        {
          "name": "Overall",
          "url": "inner/map-overall.html"
        }, {
          "name": "A",
          "url": "inner/map-a.html"
        }, {
          "name": "B",
          "url": "inner/map-b.html"
        }
      ],
      "overallPDF": "diagram.pdf",
      "mapKey": "mapkey.txt",
      "mapImagemap": "imagemap.txt"
    } // list truncated for your convenience.
  ],
  all: function() {return this.locations},
  get: function(id) {
    const isLocation = q => q.slug === id
    return this.locations.find(isLocation)
  }
}

/* 03.0 Components */
/* 03.1 Base */
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("<App /> constructor locationDataArray: " + locationDataArray);
    this.state = {
      locationData: locationDataArray,
      test: 'testing!'
    };
  }
  render() {
    console.log("<App /> locationDataArray: " + locationDataArray);
    console.log("<App /> state, testing: " + this.state.test);
    return(
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={LocationGrid} />
          <Route path='/locations/:id' component={MainMap}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

/* 03.2.0 -- Location */

class LocationGrid extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h2>Location Grid</h2>
        <div>
          <Link to="/locations">Main Map</Link>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            { // this part works with extra items in locationDataArray.
              locationDataArray.all().map(q => (
                <li key={q.slug}>
                  <Link to={`locations/${q.slug}`}>{q.location}</Link>
                </li>
              ))
            }
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

/* 03.3.0 -- Main */

class MainMap extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    console.log("Main map is on");
    const location = locationDataArray.get(
      props.match.params.id
    );
    if (!location) {
      console.log("No such location!");
    }
    if (location) {
      console.log("These tests show that the locationDataArray is accessible from this component.");
      console.log("A: props.match.params.id is: " + props.match.params.id);
      console.log("B: Location is: " + location.location);
      console.log("C: Map URL: " + location.mapUrl);
      console.log("State is: " + location);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MapHolder />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

/* 03.3.2 --- Map */
//var mapUrl = require(location.mapUrl);
class MapHolder extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("And these tests show that the locationDataArray is NOT accessible from this component.");
    console.log("1. Map location test, mapUrl: " + location.mapUrl);
    console.log("2. Map location test, slug: " + location.slug);
    return <div>
      <img id="imagemap" className="map active" src={location.mapUrl} width="1145" height="958" useMap="#samplemap" alt="" />
      <map name="samplemap" id="mapofimage">
         <area target="" alt="1" title="1" href="inner/01.html" coords="288,356,320,344,347,403,315,420" shape="poly"></area>
         {/* Additional imagemap areas. Truncated for your conveinence.*/}
      </map>
      <p>A map would be here if I could figure out the bug.</p>
      </div>
  }
}

/* 04.0.0 -- Render */

ReactDOM.render((
  <HashRouter>
    <App />
  </HashRouter>
), document.getElementById('container'));
```

`package.json` and `webpack.config.js` are all in a [git repository](https://github.com/emilyeserven/debug-requests/tree/master/map-project), if needed.

**Overall Goal**: I want to dynamically serve information to a main component and children components via a React Router route param and JSON object. Essentially, I want to be able to associate a param with an item in the object, so that the component can just refer to something like `arrayItem.itemProperty` and it can work dynamically.

I am trying to stay away from Redux as much as possible, since I'm already slightly overwhelmed by React now.

**The Current Problem**:

The array (on lines 26-55) is in the code, but anything outside of 1 component (`<MainMap />`, lines 113-138) can't access it.

An example of one of these child Components would be `<MapHolder />`, which is on lines 142-156. (I get `ReferenceError: props is not defined` in those cases.)

How would I make it so that `props.match.params.id` (or any other thing that would make this work) can be accessed to any of the children Components?

(*Note:* I'm well aware that the code isn't perfect. But this is still in early production stages, so I'd like to just resolve that one issue and hopefully the rest will clear up as a result of that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using import/export, global variables aren't shared between modules. This is a good thing, but you can export multiple variables from a module. For example, you can `export locationDataArray;` in your App.js to access it from other modules without breaking the existing exports and imports for that module. That being said you almost never want to share global data in React like this. As a general rule of thumb you should "lift" data that components depend on to the highest component in the tree that needs in (you can even make an extra parent component to make this composition easier if you'd like).

When child components rely on data from part of a parent component's data, you should generally pass in subsets of data from parent components via props. Add a `location` prop to `MapHolder` with the actual map data for the given `id`, instead of making the component look up the `id` itself. Then in `MapHolder`'s parent, render it like this:

```
<MapHolder 
  location={locationDataArray.locations.find(location => location.slug === ID)}
  />
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is [React's **Context**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) feature. It's pretty low-level, and is an unstable API likely to change at any point. Meaning: use with caution.

> In some cases, you want to pass data through the component tree without having to pass the props down manually at every level. You can do this directly in React with the powerful "context" API.

TL;DR:

First, declare the shape of the context object you will be making accessible to children, and implement `getChildChildContext` to actually return it:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
  static childContextTypes = {
    foo: PropTypes.string // or whatever you have
  };

  getChildContext() {
    return {foo: "some value"};
  }
  ...
}
```

Then, when you want to access that context in a child component, declare that you wish to do so by declaring `contextTypes` on your child component:

```
class SomeChildComponent extends React.Component {
  static childContextTypes = {
    foo: PropTypes.string
  };

  render() {
    // use in your component by accessing this.context.foo
  }
}
```

If it feels klunky, that's because it's meant to be:

> The vast majority of applications do not need to use context.
>
> If you want your application to be stable, don't use context. It is an experimental API and it is likely to break in future releases of React.

You will probably get much better results from using a state management library such as [`redux`](http://redux.js.org) or [`mobx`](https://mobx.js.org) to manage state that should be accessible from arbitrary components.

Comment: I disagree, I think it would be better to pass subsets of the data to props on child components. Context is a hack, and you don't necessarily need redux or mobx to implement something like this (though they can help a lot depending on the situation).

Comment: I actually agree with your sentiment, I was specifically answering the question posed in the title.